# Unable to return custom 'User' instance of a user object created from firestore data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, null

I have a custom 'User' class and I am trying to retrieve user's data from firestore based on its uid. I am successfully able to map it into my custom 'User' object however I cant return in from that function. Here is the code snippet:

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  // set activeUser globally
  User getCurrentUserObject(String uid) {
    User _user;
    var doc = DatabaseService().userCollection.document(uid);
    doc.get().then((doc) {
      _user = User().getUserFromData(doc.data);
      print(" user: $_user");
    });
    return _user;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.init(context);
    final currentUser = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);
    if (currentUser == null) {
      print("No user logged in");
      return Auth();
    } else {
      print("USER: ${getCurrentUserObject(currentUser.uid).email}");
      print("Current user: ${currentUser.uid}");
      return CustomerHomeScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the error snippet:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The getter 'email' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: email
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Wrapper 
lib/main.dart:20
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (30822):  user: Instance of 'User'
I/flutter (30822):  user: Instance of 'User'
```

So far I have figured that it is not able return the User instance. How can i achieve that?
Thank you :)

UPDATE: Adding `User` class which contains `getUserFromData()` method.

```
class User {
  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String phone;
  final int gender;
  final int type;
  User({this.uid, this.name, this.email, this.phone, this.gender, this.type});

  User getUserFromData(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return User(
        uid: data['uid'] ?? '',
        name: data['name'] ?? '',
        email: data['email'] ?? '',
        phone: data['phone'] ?? '',
        gender: data['gender'] ?? -1,
        type: data['type'] ?? -1);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'uid': uid,
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'phone': phone,
      'gender': gender,
      'type': type
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because your `getCurrentUserObject` method returns the `_user` variable before `doc.get()` completes. You can fix this by changing your code from using `.then` to using `await`, so you wait for the result of `doc.get()` before executing to the next line.

So, this:

```dart
User getCurrentUserObject(String uid) {
  //Rest of the code

  doc.get().then((doc) {
    _user = User().getUserFromData(doc.data);
    print(" user: $_user");
  });
  return _user;
}
```

becomes:

```dart
Future<User> getCurrentUserObject(String uid) async {
  //Rest of the code

  var doc =  await doc.get();
  _user = User().getUserFromData(doc.data);
  print(" user: $_user");
  return _user;
}
```

Comment: It is then showing I am returning a Future<User>. How do I convert it to a type of 'User'?

Comment: In the debug console it now showing as                                                                                                       flutter:  user: Instance of 'User'
flutter: USER: Instance of 'Future<User>'

Comment: You'll need to await the value too

Comment: I've updated the answer to show that, now. It should be just User now @darthwithap

Comment: I tried that too, still no god. Says 'await' applied to 'User' which is not a 'Future'

Comment: Can you update your question with your getUserFromData method content?

Comment: Sure, will do that

Comment: In order to get the user from the getCurrentUserObject method, you need to add to it like this : User user. = await getCurrentUserObject(uid);

Comment: Can't do that either, it says the await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218771/discussion-between-darthwithap-and-victor-eronmosele).